# Eclipse install error in Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows-10, java, eclipse, error-logging

Can anyone help me figure out what results in this error while I am trying to install Eclipse on my machine? It never gave me such errors before on the same exact machine.

```
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.4+11
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2019-09
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.14.0.v20190815-1111, build=4222, branch=df1f9db2f1c3e575486f818cae17bfd35a376162
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.14.0.v20190705-1542, build=4222, branch=df1f9db2f1c3e575486f818cae17bfd35a376162
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.12.0.v20190704-1252, build=4222, branch=df1f9db2f1c3e575486f818cae17bfd35a376162
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2019-09))
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Offline = false
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Mirrors = true
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to D:\Eclipse\Java Developer (SE)\eclipse
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement epp.package.java [4.13.0,5.0.0)
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.13.0,5.0.0)
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.13.0,5.0.0)
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2019-09
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/201909181001
[2019-09-22 22:04:41] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2019-09-22 22:04:45] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2019-09-22 22:04:46] Computing prerequisite plan
[2019-09-22 22:04:50] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2019-09
[2019-09-22 22:05:19] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2019-09-22 22:05:19] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2019-09 in 28.875s
[2019-09-22 22:05:19] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/201909181001
[2019-09-22 22:05:51] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2019-09-22 22:05:51] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2019-09-22 22:05:51] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2019-09-22 22:05:51] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/201909181001 in 32.413s
[2019-09-22 22:05:52] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2019-09-22 22:05:52] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:548)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1112)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=D__Eclipse_Java Developer (SE)_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Ankur\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1112)
  Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Ankur\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:194)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1763)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1225)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167)
    ... 1 more

[2019-09-22 22:05:52]
```

Probably useful info:

I have JRE and JDK 1.8 installed in the default location,
and also have JDK 1.12 installed.

I also have IntelliJ IDEA, Sublime Text, VS Code, Visual Studio, etc., installed on my system. 
All programs compile my Java files and run smoothly without any hiccup.

So I don't get why Eclipse is refusing to install. 
(I had installed Eclipse before and then removed it with IObit Uninstaller.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is

> `Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Ankur\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar`

, but I can't tell you why this jar is missing. It could be a broken leftover from a previous installation.

Download [org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar](https://mirrors.nju.edu.cn/eclipse/reddeer/snapshots/plugins/org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar) and put it in the `C:\Users\Ankur\.p2\pool\plugins` directory and restart Eclipse. With a bit of luck this was the only broken piece.

If it still doesn't work, you could delete or rename the `.p2` shared bundle pool directory and try a fresh installation.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I am Happy to report that though  org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.7.500.v20190518-1030.jar did not fix the issue           but deleting .p2 and doing a fresh install fixed the issue. Wow this was fast and thanks again.